# Invalid conversion from throwing function of type Error when some code added

Tags: ios, swift

This code normally works well:

```
let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "http://example.com")!)
        request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
        let data = "devicetoken=\(devicetoken!)&userID=1"
        request.HTTPBody = data.dataUsingEncoding(NSASCIIStringEncoding)

        let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) in

            if let response = response {

                let res = response as! NSHTTPURLResponse
                if (res.statusCode >= 200 && res.statusCode < 300)
                {

                    do {
                        let jsonData = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options:NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers ) as! NSArray
                        let json = JSON(jsonData)

                        for (_, subJSON): (String, JSON) in json[0]["events"] {

                            let titlex = subJSON["title"].string
                            let guestx = subJSON["guests"].string

                            if let guestPicsArray = subJSON["guestpics"].array {
                                if (self.myarr.count > 0) {

                                    self.myarr.removeAll()

                                }

                                for item in guestPicsArray {
                                    if let title = item.string {
                                        self.myarr.append(title)
                                    }
                                }

                  let rel1 = InboxEvents(title: titlex!, guests: guestx!, eventresim: eventresimx!, eventID : NSInteger(eventIDx!)!, arr: self.myarr)
                  self.arrayOfRels.append(rel1)

                            }

                        }


                    } catch let error as NSError {
                        print(error)
                    }


                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {

                        self.tableView.reloadData()

                    })


                } else {
                    self.boxView.removeFromSuperview()
                    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Sign in Failed!", message: "Connection Failed", preferredStyle: .Alert)

                    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .Default, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction) in

                    }))

                    self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
                }
            }  else if let error = error {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
        })
        task.resume()
```

However, when I add this code to `viewDidAppear` I get the error:

> Invalid conversion from throwing function of type '(_, _, _) throws -> ()' to non-throwing function type '(NSData?, NSURLResponse?, NSError?) -> Void'

for above code.

```
 if (PopupChat.instance().isUserLoaded == true) {
            let dialogsIDs: NSSet = NSSet(array: ["55fae39ca28f9a701d0058fb"])
            QBRequest.totalUnreadMessageCountForDialogsWithIDs(dialogsIDs as! Set<String>, successBlock: { (response: QBResponse, count: UInt, dialogs: [String : AnyObject]?) -> Void in
                let tabArray = self.tabBarController?.tabBar.items as NSArray!
                let tabItem = tabArray.objectAtIndex(3) as! UITabBarItem
                tabItem.badgeValue = String(count)
            }) { (response: QBResponse) -> Void in

            }
        }
```

Comment: If you change `catch let error as NSError` to simple `catch` does that fix it?

Comment: Wow yeah it fixed :) write your answer and i will accept it

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Change

```
} catch let error as NSError {
```

to simple

```
} catch {
```

and that should fix it.

I suppose you'd also like to know *why* that fixes it? It's because your `catch let error as NSError` doesn't mean what you think it means. In particular, it does not count as a "catch-all" `catch`, so it fails to catch every possible error. Therefore the compiler complains because your anonymous function can throw, which is not permitted.

Comment: I added a little more to explain _why_ this change is needed.

Comment: Yeah i was guessing about it, thank you for the info

Comment: Your amazing @matt ^_^